# How does Operational Transformations work when offering offline editing capabilities?

Tags: concurrency, distributed-system, collaboration

As far as I understand, OT works really well with concurrent editing. There is only one remote copy of the document, and all editors update that remote copy simultaneously. There is a concept of lag in editor actions, but the lag is never big enough to significantly change the document.

If we add offline editing capabilities, it would be possible for editors to change the master document significantly, while an editor is working with an old copy offline. Imagine some editor is working offline for one day, while the rest are editing the file online. As we are keeping the version number/hash on the remote and local copies, it would be possible to apply the transformations from the offline copy to the remote copy at the time they diverged, but considering that the remote copy changed significantly, the end result would most likely not be the desired one.

I can think of only one way of solving this issue, which would be to apply a diff and ask the user to merge the conflicts.

Is there a way with OT or any other method to avoid user intervention in cases where it is possible to keep local copies for extended periods of time?

Comment: I don't think there can be. The fundamental problem is that someone might edit a part of a document depending on its context. When the context changes, the original change is very likely not a desired outcome anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern for optimistic locking is download, edit, download, merge, upload. The trick is the human is made part of both edit and merge. You can keep an old copy as long as you like while you edit it but when you go to upload you must merge with whatever is current. The longer you wait the more you have to deal with when merging.

Works the same with git and wikipedia. It can be a pain but it's still better than pessimistic locking.